# Projekktor: supporting multiple video sizes

Tags: html5-video, projekktor

I am using Projekktor to display video, but if someone is using, say, an iPhone I want to send out a smaller video than the full 1080p that might be sent to a browser.

Is there a built-in way to do this, or do I need to do a user-agent check and create a playlist based on the device manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure Projekktor to fetch a specific video file depending on the dimensions of the video display.

To do so you need to provide multiple video video files with different resolutions for each format you want to deliver and set a "quality" property for each of them.

To alter the dimensions/quality mapping you have to set the ["playbackQualities" config option](http://www.projekktor.com/docs/configuration#playbackqualities_arraysee_below)

The whole logic is described in detail [over here](http://www.projekktor.com/docs/qualitytoggle).